Cucumber cannot find tests
I have a SpringBoot project that runs cucumber tests.
I added the following 3 dependencies:

io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.20.1
io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.20.1
io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:7.20.1

My cucumber context:
@SpringBootTest
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class CucumberIntegrationConfiguration {  }

If I run the .feature file it starts my SpringBoot project. But I need to be able to run it from gradle.
To do this I a have this test
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features/Dummy.feature",
        glue = "com.chrispie.steps")
class CucumberIntegrationTest {}

If I try to run this CucumberIntegrationTest from IntelliJ or Gradle I get Test events were not found.
Is there no way to get this working? Can it be done with JUnit 5?

You are using cucumber-junit which uses JUnit 4.
Now you didn't include your Gradle configuration, but assuming it is set up correctly for the latest version of Spring Boot, then the JUnit Platform is used. This only supports JUnit 5.
You can either use the JUnit Vintage Engine from JUnit 5 to run JUnit 4 tests with JUnit 5. Or you can use the cucumber-junit-platform-engine. The cucumber-java-skeleton shows how.
